# python- running file with command line arguments

Tags: python-2.7

There is one file lets say "demo.py" and to run that we are supposed to provide 3 command line arguments. So, we run the file like following: "demo.py arg1 arg2 arg3". I want to run this file for 10 times. How can we write another python scripts which will do this ? please help.

Comment: Please show the efforts **you** have taken.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use os.popen , for example:

```
import os
os.popen("date +%y-%m-%d").read()
```

here I used date command.